# how to get apk's name?but not yet installed in device?

Tags: android

I want to get the name of apk,That apk not yet installed in device.That apk just store in sd card,This kind of apk's name,How to get?.

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

in the Emulator,

go to **settings -> application->manage application**

it may help

Comment: @I want to cod  for that,settings -> application->manage application used for display Installed application list,I don't want it,I want to *.apk only,How?